# stbi_load doesn't return any value

Tags: c++, stb-image

I'm trying to load some images with stb_image to an `unsigned char*`. The code goes like this:

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>

namespace rhino {

    Texture::Texture(const std::string& file) {
        stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);

        buffer = stbi_load(file.c_str(), &width, &height, &bpp, 4);
         ...
```

The `buffer`, `bpp`, `width` and `height` variables are declared in the `Texture`class. After the `stbi_load` call, `width`, `height` and `bpp` are 0. I am certain that the filepath is correct but even if I enter a wrong path, the same resuts are occuring. I don't know if stbi_image is supposed to print something to the console if an error occurs but no text is printed there.

[EDIT]
Does somebody actually know what is supposed to happen if stb_image cannot read a image?

Comment: I believe your last parameter should be 0

Comment: No that wasn't it. Same results

Comment: Something else, maybe it doesn't matter, but I believe you need "stb_image.h" and not <stb_image.h>

Comment: About your edit: When stbi_load fails it should return nullptr

Comment: I have put the stb_image.h in the inculde directory of my compiler so I have to do ´#include <stb_image.h>´

Comment: Ok it indeed returns an nullptr

Comment: Can you figure out why stb_image cannot read that image?

Comment: Do you use an absolute or relative path? Because that might make a big difference

Comment: Now I tried it with the absolute path and it actually worked surprisingly. Because I already compiled a shader using the relative path I thought that it would work with textures the same way. Apparently it doesn't. No idea why

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the stbi_failure_reason() to get a hint of what is going wrong.  If the stbi_load() works fine, stbi_failure_reason() returns null.  If not, it returns the actual error.

```
 buffer = stbi_load(file.c_str(), &width, &height, &bpp, 4);

  if(stbi_failure_reason())
    std::cout << stbi_failure_reason();
```

In your case, where you were using the relative path instead of an absolute path, it would have returned a message, "Can't fopen".  That way you could have guessed its pointing to the wrong folder.  If the image type that you were using is not supported by STBI, you would have received a message "unknown image type" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to use an absolute path because your stb_image.h is somewhere outside your project directory. This way, it will look for the relative path of your image from the directory the header is in. and not in your project directory.

You have two options to fix this:

- Use absolute paths
- Move stb_image.h to your project directory, preferably at the root of it

Comment: I just described the problem here, the fix is to use absolute paths or add your stb_image.h header to the project and move it to your project directory